# AJAX is not working in rails 6 with my code , my create.js.erb code is not working , i have to reload every time to show my message in index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-6

---

**messages_controller.rb FILE:**

```
 class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @messages = Message.all
    @message = Message.new
  end
 
  def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)
    @messages = Message.all
    respond_to do |format|
        if @message.save
            format.html { redirect_to @message, notice: 'message was successfully created'}
            format.js
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @message }
        end
    end 
  end
  
  private
  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:body)
  end   

end
```

---

**index.html.erb FILE:**

```
  <table>
  <tbody>
  <%= render partial: 'message', collection: @messages %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<%= render 'form', message: @message %>
```

---

*# i remove the code from CREATE.JS.ERB but it results in no change in server (port:3000)#*
**create.js.erb FILE:**

```
$('table#bands tbody').append("<%= j render @message %>");
```

---

**_message.html.erb FILE:**

```
<tr>
  <td><%= message.body %></td>
</tr>
```

---

**_form.html.erb FILE:**

```
 <%= form_with(model: message) do |f| %>
 <div class="col-sm-8"> 
        <%= f.text_area :body, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Message Body" %>
 </div>

 <div class="btn-group">
        <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

---

**routes.rb FILE:**

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :messages
  root 'messages#index'
 
end
```

---

**schema.rb FILE:**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_07_23_045320) do

  create_table "messages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

end
```

---

> Ruby on rails

Comment: So what is the question

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have a read of the guide on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically, don't just post your code; include some description of what you are trying do accomplish, what specifically is happening in your case, and a minimal, reproducible example with *relevant* code -- For example, if you are having trouble with AJAX, we don't need your ``schema.rb``, etc. Please read the guide and have a go at editing your question accordingly.

Comment: Having said that, your jQuery selector is ``$('table#bands tbody')`` (find a table with the ID 'bands' and select its ``<tbody>``, but the table element in ``index.html.erb`` does have an ID of ``bands``. That would be one reason why you get no update.